# LINQ query OR Expression and using one Query Variable

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to specify one query variable and set it based on the if condition block that is being satisfied but my code returns an error, and when trying to convert the results to an array

```
return query.ToArray()
```

it tells me

> `IQueryable` does not contain a definition for `ToArray` and no accessible extension

How do I resolve this?

```
public IEnumerable<PfBalanceValidation> GetPfBalanceValidationList(string code, string name)
{
    using (IFRSContext entityContext = new IFRSContext()) {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(code)){

            var query;

            query = (from e in entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>()
                         where e.Productcode == name
                         select e);

        } else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {

            query = (from e in entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>()
                         where e.Glcode == code
                         select e);

        } else {

            query = (from e in entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>()
                         where e.Productcode == name //&& e.Glcode == code
                         select e);

       }

       return query.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely just missing the `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Your code cannot possibly compile. `var query` without assignment will fail. And that `query` variable is in bad scope, so it cannot be used outside of it.

Comment: Also `query` will not be defined anywhere other than the first `if` block. Another reason it won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you could also do something like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
{
    return entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>().Where(e => e.Productcode == name);
}
else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    return entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>().Where(e => e.Glcode == code);
}
else
{
    return entityContext.Set<PfBalanceValidation>().Where(e => e.Productcode == name);
}
```

Comment: ( e ) is undefined, and does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry It was supposed to be "e => e.Productcode == name". I fixed this just now.

Comment: please, but how do you return the output as an array,  from here - query.ToArray(), that was another issue i was having..

Comment: The return type is not an array so you don't have to return an array. If you want an array then change the return type to an array and then append .ToArray() at the end of what you are returning.